# Visual C++ - overriding a function imported from a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, c++11

I'm trying to override a specific function in kernel32.dll. Is it somehow possible to redefine that function in a static library and force the executable to use the one in the static library? I guess the different linkage could become a problem.

It would be possible to override it with my own custom DLL. However the problem is that the DLL itself needs to link to kernel32.dll, so it ignores my definition of that function.

EDIT: I got it working with my own DLL. When building it, link time code generation needs to be disabled. What about linking the overridden function statically though?

Comment: I'm hesitant to change the title to "... imported from KERNEL32.DLL". A shim DLL can be a solution, but Kernel32.DLL is a special DLL: it's the one DLL that you must link against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is no big problem. Functions are defined as `__dllimport`, but that does not specify *which* DLL they're imported from. The linker simply picks the first import library that provides them. Therefore,. just pass your library first. In MSVC, you'll need to disable "include standard libraries", as those precede custom libraries.

Comment: I'm passing my own DLL first now, and it's working as expected. However when building that DLL I had to disable LTCG, because otherwize the linker seems to process kernel32.lib before my module (I wonder if there's a way to use LTCG and still be able to build the DLL). Any idea if there's a way to do the overrides with a static library? Instead of having to build your own DLL.

Comment: A static library isn't linked yet, so it **can't** link against Kernel32.DLL or your override.

Comment: The only reason I'm unable to do the override statically is, because the import is done with __declspec(dllimport). Would it be possible to make __declspec(dllimport) also look for functions that are not in a DLL?

Comment: @NFRCR: You just told the linker "don't bother looking for this name in the parts I provide now (object files + static libs), it's a DLL import" and then want to say "look for this name in a static library". That's going to be flaky at best.

Comment: I've been investigating this. It's possible to override a DLL function in your own object files if you redefine that function with __declspec(dllexport) (an executable that exports a function). 

However the CRT seems to ignore it and still links to kernel32.dll. I finally made the executable to self-import the function. The CRT linked to it, but the behaviour of the executable was unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want custom behavior for a Windows API function in kernel32.dll. If so, you need to hook into the Windows API. One way to do this is to use [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). Haven't tried it myself but here's a link to a CodeProject article - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours.

Answer (score 1):

**If your application already exists and cannot be modified**, then

you can write proxy dll. I.e. make your own dll called kernel32.dll, place it into application directory, and make your proxy dll provide all function application needs. Of course, your custom dll should redirect all calls it doesn't override to original kernel32.dll - by loading original dll using LoadLibrary.

Because LoadLibrary is provided by kernel32 and you're proxying kernel32, most likely you'll have to name your proxy dll kernel33.dll and patch original exe and make it load kernel33 instead of kernel32.

The whole thing is is pain, and to do it successfully you should be at least familiar with cli(command line interface - cmd.exe on windows) and dumpbin utility. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically) outdated tutorial can get you started.

Alternatively you could attempt to use dll injection or similar techniques. There's also ["Detours"](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/intellectualproperty/iplicensing/programs/detours.aspx) library which I haven't used (not sure why would I want to bother with it if I can make a proxy dll).

**if you have source code access to your application** and only specific part of program needs different routine...

Then simply make custom routine with whatever name you want (say, `myLoadLibrary`). Then make a header that uses `#define` to redefine your routine. I.e. something like `#define LoadLibrary myLoadLibrary`. Include that header in every file where you need override, and make sure it is included after `<windows.h>`.

Comment: This isn't going to work. "your custom dll should redirect all calls it ... by loading original [Kernel32.dll] using LoadLibrary". That's a chicken and egg problem: `LoadLibrary` comes from Kernel32.dll, so it can't be used to load Kernel32.dll

Comment: The function renaming is no problem; it's the first suggestion which doesn't work.

Comment: @MSalters: "you'll have to name your proxy dll kernel33.dll". It looks like you missed that part.

Comment: No, I didn't. How is your proxy "kernel33" DLL going to call `LoadLibraryW("kernel32.dll");` ? It can't. To call `LoadLibraryW`, kernel32.dll must already be loaded. This problem does not go away by renaming either DLL - the chicken-and-egg problem is due to the content, not the names.