GCC C++ Client code affects the inner workings of a dynamic library
There is a shared library and an executable that is supposed to use the library.
Inside the library there is an auxiliary function that is not exported anywhere. The client code defines the function with the same signature.
During the runtime the library calls the auxiliary function, but the client version is called.
Here's the library:
//lib.h file
#ifndef OBR_EXPORTS_H
#define OBR_EXPORTS_H
void libFun();
#endif //OBR_EXPORTS_H

//lib.cpp file
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream>
void myFun(){std::cout << "function from Lib\n";}
void libFun() {myFun();}

//main.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "lib.h"

void myFun(){std::cout << "function from main\n";}

int main() {
    myFun();
    libFun();
}

cmake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(funLib SHARED lib.h lib.cpp)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE funLib)

When the code is compiled g++ into .so and program is run on linux the output is:
function from main
function from main

The code that is compiled separately to be an independent library is instead affected by external code that is supposed to only use it as black box.
If the library was compiled into .dll and run on windows (the example code here will not) the output would be:
function from main
function from Lib

This is what I'm trying to achieve. In reality both the library and the client are massive independently developed projects that you cannot just go and try to rename everything in them. In fact, turning one of them into dynamic library was an attempt to minimize their interface.
How to protect the functions inside the library from being overshadowed by the code outside and prevent external code from accessing them (except for specific set of interface ones)?

If you have two functions with the same same signature but different implementations then the program breaks the One Definition Rule ie UB.  Put the internal library function(s) into their own namespace.

And to make it even safer, put the functions that are not meant to be available from the outside inside an anonymous namespace.

All of your library should be in its own namespace.  Then you can have sub namespaces in it like a details namespace.  It is common convention that using or messing with anything in the details namespace is a use at your own risk, it is not part of the supported implementation and is subject to be changed at any time.

C++ and the C++ abstract machine have no notion of linkers, loaders, .so, and .dll.  When the linker resolves the DLL, it will pre-link the DLL to the DLL's own myFun.  All is not lost, there are several options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9566836/4641116

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility
